# NHibernate Envers not created audit tables

Tags: nhibernate-envers

I have tried with following code

```
config.SetEnversProperty(ConfigurationKey.DefaultSchema, "audit");
config.SetEnversProperty(ConfigurationKey.RevisionFieldName, "Rev");
config.SetEnversProperty(ConfigurationKey.RevisionTypeFieldName, "RevType");
config.SetEnversProperty(ConfigurationKey.AuditTableSuffix, "_Audit");
config.SetEnversProperty(ConfigurationKey.StoreDataAtDelete, false);
var enversCfg = new AttributeConfiguration();                        
config.IntegrateWithEnvers(enversCfg);
```

But I got an error, the reason is not created audit tables, anyone please help

2014-02-28 00:47:03,200 DEBUG 6 CSL: NHibernate.SQL METHOD: lambda_method LINE:0 - INSERT INTO audit.REVINFO (REVTSTMP) VALUES (@p0); select SCOPE_IDENTITY();